# how to enforce multitable join in hive to do a map only process

Tags: hive

I am trying to do multitable join in hive and that is working slow because on skew in reducers. So my question is how to enforce multitable join in hive to do a MAP ONLY process (i.e. no reducer)?

Answer (score 0):

A map only job is only possible when the query processor during run time decides that one is small and the other is large the small table size can be configured by `hive.smalltable.filesize`.

**How Map join is done?**

Before the normal MR job starts a local MR task is started to move the data from small table into a hash table. Then that is serialized and put into disk and hashtable file is compressed to a tar file and when the MR job starts this is then put into diatributed cache and passed to all mappers and in the local path of that tasktracker the file would be untared and kept for doing the join.The large table records are passed through and join is done by looking up in the buffer(local dir of TT). This would be good moreover you do a lookup kind of operation.

**With SKEWED BY option:**

If there is a skew in the reduce side may be you could try creating the table with [SKEWED BY](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-SkewedTables) option or alter the table with [SKEWED BY](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTableSkewedorStoredasDirectories) option. That would split up the value which you provide for the key in the statement into two or more different files or directories. So ideally the skew value would go into a separate directory and others keys into separate default directory.Since it has the metadata of the skewed column name and so that a join could make use of that. I think the implementation is the one with separate directory(skew value) would be joined with the other table(corresponding dir) to a mapside join and not sure though. However this needs a change in metastore.

Comment: I have the small table size as `-rw-r--r--   3 biadmin biadmin     100737 2015-10-25 19:07 /biginsights/hive/warehouse/db2.db/smalltable/000000_0`.  I have executed the below `hive> set hive.smalltable.filesize=104857600;
hive> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM db1.largetable A INNER JOIN db2.smalltable B ON A.col1 = B.col1;
Total MapReduce jobs = 2
Stage-1 is selected by condition resolver.
Launching Job 1 out of 2
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 57
......
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 172; number of reducers: 57`
Still considering 57 reducers

Comment: The query processor will automatically do a map join based on the size from hive version 0.11. In prior versions we have to set hive.auto.convert.join = true. Else you could use comments with MAPJOIN. select /+mapjoin(x)/ * from x join y on x.k=y.k.

Comment: `/* +MAPJOIN(b) */` stands for mainly bucketed map join in hive which is not my intention I just want the process to be a MAP ONLY process. No REDUCERS

Comment: Still I have tried what you have said, somehow it is not working `hive> set hive.smalltable.filesize=104857600;
hive> set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
hive> SELECT /* +MAPJOIN(B) */ COUNT(1) FROM db1.largetable A INNER JOIN db2.smalltable B ON A.col1 = B.col1;
Total MapReduce jobs = 2
Stage-1 is selected by condition resolver.
Launching Job 1 out of 2
..................  Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 172; number of reducers: 57`

Comment: The hint doesn't mean bucketed map join. if we have to use bucketed map join then we have to set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin as true. By the way which version of hive are you using? The hints are deprecated from 0.7 and if use a version after that just set hive.auto.convert.join as true and remove the hint and try running it.

Comment: I am using hive version 0.12

Comment: no luck without the hint as well. `hive> set hive.smalltable.filesize=104857600;
hive> set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
hive> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM db1.largetable A INNER JOIN db2.smalltable B ON A.col1 = B.col1;
Total MapReduce jobs = 2
Stage-1 is selected by condition resolver.
Launching Job 1 out of 2
.......
.......
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 172; number of reducers: 57`

Comment: I am wondering whether COUNT(1) could be achieved without a reducer call. I don't think so it certainly require a reducer can you try replacing that with a column name.And can you remove the INNER keyword. The reason is this doesn't work for right and full outer join. Removing doesn't hold any significance but may be something is configured/written based on the keyword.

Comment: Sorry no luck again. `hive> set hive.smalltable.filesize=104857600;
hive> set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
hive> SELECT A.col1,A.col2 FROM db1.largetable A JOIN db2.smalltable B ON A.col1 = B.col1;
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Stage-1 is selected by condition resolver.
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 57
.......
.......
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 172; number of reducers: 57`